# Android EditText string equal to pre-defined string

Tags: java, android

I'm only a  beginner in Android programming and I have a question, I've been trying to find a way to use an if statement to enable a button. What I want is that if what the user inputs into the EditText is equal to a string I have defined, I want the button to be enabled, and disabled otherwise. I have used TextWatcher, and I can do this task using an integer, but I am wondering if this is possible with strings too? any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always use a `setError` on your edittext if the user hasn't enter any data in the `edittext`. On clicking the button, use an `if` statement to check if the text in the `edittext` is equal to the string you defined. If not, use the `setError` to your `edittext` to display an error message and return `false`. Hence, only when your function returns true, allow the button's function to be enabled.

Otherwise you could always try, `myButton.setEnabled(false);`
Set it to true when your strings are matched.

If you want the XML equivalent try `android:clickable`

```
String s= et.getText().toString();
    if(s.equals("hurray"))
    {
        b.setClickable(true);

    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dude, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could listen to the text using textchange listener

```
yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

      public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        // you can call or do what you want with your EditText here
        // compare the editable text s with your fixed string. 
        // if this matched with your predefined text. enable your button click. 

      }

      public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
   });
```